# Why can't I see my app instead of default nginx test page in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, unicorn

After following all the steps in deploying a Rails app in digitalocean using Unicorn and nginx as outlined in the following link [enter link description here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5)
, entering my IP address in the browser leads me to default nginx landing page which says: "This is the default index.html page that is distributed with nginx on Fedora. It is located in /usr/share/nginx/html.

You should now put your content in a location of your choice and edit the root configuration directive in the nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

Here is **my etc/nginx/ngingx.conf**:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
 include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
     log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
         }
     }


# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;


          ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
 #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
 #        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
 #        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
 #        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 #        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 #
 #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
 #        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
 #
 #        location / {
 #        }
 #
 #        error_page 404 /404.html;
 #            location = /40x.html {
 #        }
 #
 #        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
 #            location = /50x.html {
 #        }
 #    }
```

And here is /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf :

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

 server {


    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /root/my_app/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
     }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

And also the config/unicorn.rb

```
#application root path
app_root = "/var/www/mav"

# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory app_root

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "#{app_root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "#{app_root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{app_root}/log/unicorn.log"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

When access the unicorn logs:

```
tail -20 /var/log/nginx/error.log


2017/12/10 05:06:30 [warn] 8810#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 05:06:30 [warn] 8818#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 05:08:31 [error] 8826#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.104.119.69, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201", referrer: "http://138.197.195.201/"
2017/12/10 05:29:51 [warn] 19171#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 05:29:51 [warn] 19176#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 05:43:49 [warn] 12191#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 05:43:50 [warn] 12203#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 06:01:29 [warn] 11819#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 06:01:30 [warn] 11825#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/12/10 06:01:48 [error] 11833#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/mav/" is forbidden, client: 100.12.198.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201"
2017/12/10 06:01:50 [error] 11833#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/mav/" is forbidden, client: 100.12.198.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201"
2017/12/10 06:01:52 [error] 11833#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/mav/" is forbidden, client: 100.12.198.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201"
 2017/12/10 06:04:57 [error] 11833#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/mav/" is forbidden, client: 100.12.198.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201"
2017/12/10 06:04:58 [error] 11833#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/mav/" is forbidden, client: 100.12.198.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201"
2017/12/10 06:04:59 [error] 11833#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/mav/" is forbidden, client: 100.12.198.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201"
2017/12/10 06:04:59 [error] 11833#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/mav/" is forbidden, client: 100.12.198.208, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.195.201"
2017/12/10 06:11:38 [emerg] 30474#0: unknown directive "And" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:91
 2017/12/10 06:12:10 [emerg] 31474#0: unknown directive "And" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:91
2017/12/10 06:19:31 [emerg] 12641#0: unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:89
2017/12/10 06:43:30 [emerg] 24459#0: unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:89
```

Comment: Have you restart Nginx service after deploy?

Comment: yes I have restarted it

Comment: Try to replace `/root/my_app/public;` with the full path or your app

Comment: Did. I am starting to wonder whether \ etc/nginx/ngingx.conf root should be /usr/share/nginx/html or /var/www/my_app

Comment: @jungleMan You got the point. Check my answer below then you can clarify yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are several misconfigurations. Since you don't provide all of them, I will list them here, then you can check yourself

1. Where is the folder where your code locate?
   I assume it in `/var/www/mav` as you wrote it in your `config/unicorn.rb`. It will be your starting point.
2. The root for your `nginx.conf` should be `/var/www/mav/public`
3. You should remove any `index.html` file in the `/var/www/mav/public` folder
4. Your NginX listen to the unix socket of Unicorn, but your `unicorn.rb` did not configure it.
   Here is what I get from your setup document

   ```
   # Unicorn socket
   listen "/tmp/unicorn.[app name].sock"
   listen "/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock"
   ```
5. After start your `unicorn`, you should check if it started correctly or not ( ex: via log, via `ps` command ... )

P/S: Your NginX config name should be **etc/nginx/nginx.conf** ( without the last **g**)

Comment: I just added the unicorn logs I get after implementing your changes

Comment: There is something went wrong with your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. I guess you have 2 configuration files + wrong syntax.

Comment: @jungleMan Can you add your new `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file after update? Remember to remove your old `/etc/nginx/ngingx.conf` if you changed filename.